# NSWindow won't allow resize until NSSplitView has been adjusted

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a new app (macOS, Cocoa, Objective-C) which is an Concrete subclass of NSWindow which contains a concrete subclass of NSSplitview with horizontal split. The splitview has some custom views in each panel.

The main window is resizable, but it won't allow you to resize in the normal manner (by dragging the frame) until you have nudged the splitview divider. After that the window can be resized at will.

Any ideas why the window won't resize until the splitview has been nudged?

Comment: Is the issue reproduceable without the subclasses?

Comment: Yes indeed. It is exactly the same.